# html5 history api fallback?

Tags: jquery, ajax, browser-history, html5-history

I am new javascript. I managed to create a .load script which loads in different views (with alot of help).
Its working but I don't know how to tell the script to load in the appropriate view when someone uses a url like www.mydomain.com/#view3

Apart from this already existing problem i want to replace my current load script with the html5 history api and fall back to the old one when the clients browser doesnt support it.
how can i find out if the browser supports the history api and if not how to make a fallback? i know modernizr supports css classes for fallbacks. dooes a lib exists for the same thing in javascript?

I know its alot im asking for. im currently reading myself in, but im kinda pressurized :-/

this is my corrent code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".con").load("views/startseite.php", function () {
        $(".scroll").jScrollPane({mouseWheelSpeed:20});$(".jspDrag").hide();$(".jspScrollable").mouseenter(function(){$(this).find(".jspDrag").stop(!0,!0).fadeIn()});$(".jspScrollable").mouseleave(function(){$(this).find(".jspDrag").stop(!0,!0).fadeOut()})
    });
    $("nav a").click(function (a) {
        a.preventDefault();
        a = $(this).attr("href").split("/").pop().split(".").shift();
        $(".con").hide().load("views/" + a + ".php", function () {
            $(".con").fadeIn("fast",
                function () {
                    $(".scroll").jScrollPane({mouseWheelSpeed:20});$(".jspDrag").hide();$(".jspScrollable").mouseenter(function(){$(this).find(".jspDrag").stop(!0,!0).fadeIn("slow")});$(".jspScrollable").mouseleave(function(){$(this).find(".jspDrag").stop(!0,!0).fadeOut("slow")})})
        });
        document.title = "My-Domain.com | " + (a.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + a.substr(1));
        location.hash = a;
        return !1
    })
    $(document).on('submit', 'form.ajax', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var that = $(this),
            url = that.attr('action'),
            type = that.attr('method'),
            data = {};
        that.find('[name]').each(function (index, value) {
            var that = $(this),
                name = that.attr('name'),
                value = that.val();
            data[name] = value
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: type,
            data: data,
            success: function () {
                $(".flipbox").flippy({
                    color_target: "",
                    duration: "500",
                    verso: "Anything!",
                    onFinish: function () {
                        $("#no-color").css("background-color", "transparent");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
    $(document).on('submit', 'form.lebenslauf', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: './secure/secure.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                code: $('input[name=bewerbung]').val()
            },
            success: function (resp) {
                if (resp.substr(0, 5) == "Error") {
                    $('.error').html(resp);
                } else {
                    $('.flipbox').flippy({
                        duration: "500",
                        verso: resp,
                        onFinish: function () {
                            $(".flipbox").css("background-color", "transparent");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well unfortunately I can't help you very much with your problem of loading different views, but I think I can provide some insight on the second part of your question.

Most of the browserstate functionality you're looking for can be handled with history.js:
https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/

It provides you with simple pre-built functions and all the cross-browser support is handled behind the scenes. When the html5 history api is not available it automatically uses a hash instead.

Hopefully that's the library you're looking for, good luck!